# How to manipulate input in bash program with python

Tags: python, linux, bash, input

I have the problem that I want to start a program in bash with a python script and then give input to that program. Right now it looks like this:

```
string="somestringthatstartsprogram"
os.system(string)
```

and then the program waits for input, so I need something like this:

```
os.system(string, <<< "0")
```

the input is always 0. <<< works in a bash script but I don't know how to do that in python. Searching for this problem gives a lot of answers for the other way round, using input from bash to python, but that's not what I want.

I would be very glad if you could give me a hint how to solve that :)

kind regards,
bwp

Edit:
Thank you very much for that useful hint. I've just started with python and don't now what I did exactly but it worked. Here is the solution:

```
#import subprocess
#import shlex
string="somestringthatstartsprogram"
args = shlex.split(string)
p = subprocess.Popen(args,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout_data = p.communicate(input='0')[0]
```

Comment: See the `subprocess` module. It has a much easier interface than raw `os.system`.

Comment: Thank you very much for that useful hint. I've just started with python and don't now what I did exactly but it worked. Here is the solution: